# CSS Custom variables in custom element and shadow dom not resolved by IDE or browser

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element, css-variables

I have been trying to use CSS custom properties within a custom element, like so:

```
function tpl(raw){
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  template.innerHTML = raw;
  return template;
}

const templateNode = tpl`
  <style>
  :root {
    --default-text-color: red;  // IDE squiggles
  }
  
  p { color: var(--default-text-color); } 
  </style>

  <p>Test</p>
`

class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    const sd = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    sd.appendChild(templateNode.content.cloneNode(true))
  }

  connectedCallback(){
    console.log('my-element connected')
  }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement)
```

The custom property: `--default-text-color` doesn't seem to be recognized by IDE and it is not resolved by the browser.

[image: squiggles]

So apparently I am missing some crucial bit of info as to why the above code is not supposed to work. Can anyone explain?

NB. I am aware of Constructable StyleSheets and its `adoptedStyleSheets` member, but it only seems to be a proposed solution at this moment, not fully supported by all browsers yet. I am hoping to find a solution which works in all browsers that support css custom properties and custom elements.

Comment: I'm not sure there is :root in shadow DOM; shouldn't it be :host? Also there is probably `var()` missing around custom property retrieval (?).

Comment: I tried `:host` as well, same result. I corrected the lack of `var` - it was simply an editorial mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Myf in the comments, your use of `:root` instead of `:host` is your problem.

You can use `:root` at document level (or any CSS selector),
because CSS properties cascade into shadowDOM.

(unrelated) You are also overcomplicating code; but you can't be blamed,
*all* blogs and even MDN documentation show bloated code

```js
customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super() // sets AND returns 'this' scope
      .attachShadow({ mode: 'open'}) // sets AND returns 'this.shadowRoot'
      .innerHTML = `<style>
                      :host{ --textcolor: green }
                      p { color: var(--textcolor,red); background: var(--bgcolor,grey) } 
                    </style>
                    <h1>Hello Web Component</h1>`
  }
})
```

```css
:root {
  --bgcolor: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<my-element></my-element>
```

#### text added by Trusktr:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68934167/4

Note if you do it that way, `--textcolor` is no longer inheritable from an ancestor element that is above the custom element to be styled.

Placing your vars in `:root` is one way to keep them inheritable, but not ideal for code inside a custom element.

Mapping them to "internal" vars is another way we can do this so that we can keep properties inheritable:

```css
:host {
  --textcolor--: var(--textcolor, red);
}
```

Then use `--textcolor--` (using a convention of two trailing slashes to mark a property as "internal") where the style is needed:

```
p {
  color: var(--textcolor--);
}
```

Now `--textcolor` is inheritable because it will not be overriden by a value on `:host`.

Comment: Note if you do it this way, `--textcolor` is no longer inheritable from an ancestor element that is above the custom element to be styled.

Comment: I don't get your ``--textcolor`` update you now added to my answer; how can the **outside** of the WC now set the textcolor?? What is the point of setting a CSS property **inside** a WC, when people in Userland can't change it?

Comment: AH! you are adding an example with postfix ``--`` and NOT using that in code. Can you please shorten the example and make it less confusing. Better yet, instead of adding 50% to someone else his answer, add your own answer, so it can be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: No, I still don't have a clue what you mean. See https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/cwqb8tz5/ where I added a CSS property in a location you say is not possible. There are no "internal" CSS properties. If ``:host`` (for some weird reason) should not inherit a CSS property, then it should create its own